# Geopandas Loop over shapefile subset and run function (Segregation Package)

Tags: python, loops, geopandas, shapefile

I have a large shapefile of rows of smaller area (cities) polygons grouped with a field to a series of larger geographic areas (counties) and need to run a function for subsets of the shapefile (not for the entire shapefile but separately for each larger area using the data from the smaller area rows).
The function I am using is from the Segregation python package.

**The code below successfully runs the Segregation function for a single large area**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import segregation
import pandas as pd

df = gpd.read_file('hiddenlocation.shp')
from segregation.singlegroup import AbsoluteCentralization, Gini
cent = AbsoluteCentralization(df, group_pop_var='BlackNH20', total_pop_var='Total20')
cent.statistic
```

**The code below successfully generates subsets of the shapefile grouped by the COG field**

```
dfs = {}
for cog, df_cog in df.groupby('COG'):
    dfs[cog] = df_cog
dfs['CTMetro'].head()
```

Next, I would like to run a script that applies the function from the first set of code to the shapefile subsets generated in the second set of code above.

In short, I am hoping to link these two pieces of code so that the script runs a loop over the dataframe using the COG field as a filter, then applies the AbsoluteCentralization function for each dataframe subset representing a unique large area. Finally, the statistic from this series of looped functions should be outputted into a new dictionary with 2 columns containing the following fields (cog, statistic)

I have attempted a few different solutions but can't seem to figure out how to run the function for each iteration of the loop.